# Is it possible to change a current app for a newer one in Apple Store and Play Store?

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, google-play, app-store, ionic4

Is it possible to change/update an app in Apple Store and Play Store to a new one?
I have an app already published in both Apple Store and Play Store and I made them using Ionic v1 and as I have encountered this issue on Uiwebview (https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=12232019b)

So i plan to make a new one using Ionic v4 and submit it as my Ionic v1 could this be possible? if yes how to do it? do i just need to resubmit it using the same .keystore file?

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely publish an update for an already released app on Play Store or App Store.

**Make sure that the package name is same**

**For Play Store:**

- Increase android-versionCode in config.xml file. Version code is used by PlayStore to identify whether a new update is available.
- Create a production build with command `ionic cordova build android --prod`
- Use the same keystore file that you used for signing the release build of original ionic-1 App.

I prefer to create a release build using Android Studio. Just import the `<your ionic project root>platform/android/` folder in Android Studio. Then you can follow this guide to create the release build: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing

[image]

- You can also use commands to create a release build. You can find them here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/guide/publishing.html
- In Play Store console, Create a new release. Follow this guide: https://customersupport.doubledutch.me/hc/en-us/articles/360001395033-Android-How-to-Update-an-App-in-the-Google-Play-Developer-Console

**For iOS:**

- Create a production build using command `ionic cordova build android --prod`
- Go to platforms/iOS and open the `.xcworkspace` file in Xcode.
- Login into Xcode and get your provisioning certificates.`(Xcode-> Preferences-> Accounts)`
- Then in Xcode, under General Tab, increase the Version Code and Build Number. App Store uses Build number to track updates.
- In Top menu, select Product-> Destination -> Generic iOS Device
- Then create an archive Product-> Archive
- To create an update in App Store developer console, follow these steps: https://customersupport.doubledutch.me/hc/en-us/articles/360009686874-iOS-Updating-an-Existing-App-under-your-Apple-Developer-Account